# Distribution whose PDF is $(n+1) p^k \binom{n}{k} (1-p)^{n-k}$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If you have k successes in n trials of a binary experiment with 
probability p of success, your estimate of p is distributed as $(n+1) 
p^k \binom{n}{k} (1-p)^{n-k}$.

I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid, but what is the name of this 
distribution? Negative binomial seems close, and it might be a beta 
distribution, but I can't figure out which one. It's variance turns 
out to be $\frac{(k+1) (-k+n+1)}{(n+2)^2 (n+3)}$ which just seems 
plain weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a function of $p$, that's the [Beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)($\alpha$, $\beta$) distribution with parameters $\alpha=k+1$ and $\beta=n-k+1$. The scaling constant for this Beta distribution is $\Gamma(n+2)\over \Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)$ which equals $(n+1)!\over k!(n-k)!$ which equals $(n+1){n\choose k}$.

Comment: Is there a simplification (to another distribution) in the special case where k and n are nonnegative integers with n >= k ?

Comment: @barrycarter Other than Beta, I don't think there's a different name in that case.